# How can I check which CPU chipset do I have?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I want to check if I have a Snapdragon or Exynos chipset. How could I check this quickly? I need this info because I plan to root my phone, and it matters, exactly which chipset the phone has.

I have tried to find this info inside the phone, but no luck.

Do I need to install some app, or can I get this info without additional software, by reading it somewhere inside the phone?

Comment: You can use [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The U.S. variant of the mobile phone is powered by the Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 processor, while Samsung's own Exynos 8 processor powers the international iteration of the phone.

http://www.techtimes.com/articles/144278/20160326/galaxy-s7-snapdragon-vs-exynos-speed-test-which-model-is-faster.htm

Answer (score 20):

First you'll need to find your device's Model Number.

You can find this in *Settings > About Device*, under the field *Model Number*.

It may look something like: `SM-G930F`.

If your device is in a state where you cannot navigate to *Settings > About Device*, please refer to the *bottom of my post* for alternative methods to lookup your model number.

---

Once you've found your model number, you can look up its chipset in [my source](https://www.techwalls.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-model-numbers-differences/), or in the tables below:

### Samsung Galaxy S7 SM-G930

```
╔══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Country / Region ║ Cell Phone Carrier ║    Model Number    ║    Chipset     ║
╠══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Canada           ║ BELL MOBILITY      ║ SM-G930W8          ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ China            ║ ALL                ║ SM-G9300, SM-G9308 ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ Europe           ║ ALL                ║ SM-G930F           ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ KT                 ║ SM-G930K           ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ LGT                ║ SM-G930L           ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ SKT                ║ SM-G930S           ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Southeast Asia   ║ ALL                ║ SM-G930FD Duos*    ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ US               ║ CRICKET            ║ SM-G930AZ          ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ AT&T               ║ SM-G930A           ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ METROPCS           ║ SM-G930T1          ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ LTE RURAL VERIZON  ║ SM-G930R6          ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ C SPIRE WIRELESS   ║ SM-G930R7          ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ SPRINT PCS         ║ SM-G930P           ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ T-MOBILE           ║ SM-G930T           ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ US CELLULAR        ║ SM-G930R4          ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ VERIZON            ║ SM-G930V           ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ UNLOCKED           ║ SM-G930U           ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
╚══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════╝
* Dual-sim
```

### Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge SM-G935

```
╔══════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Country / Region ║ Cell Phone Carrier ║  Model Number   ║    Chipset     ║
╠══════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Canada           ║ BELL MOBILITY      ║ SM-G935W8       ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ China            ║ ALL                ║ SM-G9350        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ Europe           ║ ALL                ║ SM-G935F        ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ KT                 ║ SM-G935K        ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ LGT                ║ SM-G935L        ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Korea            ║ SKT                ║ SM-G935S        ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ Southeast Asia   ║ ALL                ║ SM-G935FD Duos* ║ Exynos 8890    ║
║ US               ║ CRICKET            ║ SM-G935AZ       ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ AT&T               ║ SM-G935A        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ METROPCS           ║ SM-G935T1       ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ LTE RURAL VERIZON  ║ SM-G935R6       ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ C SPIRE WIRELESS   ║ SM-G935R7       ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ SPRINT PCS         ║ SM-G935P        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ T-MOBILE           ║ SM-G935T        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ US CELLULAR        ║ SM-G935R4       ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ VERIZON            ║ SM-G935V        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
║ US               ║ UNLOCKED           ║ SM-G935U        ║ Snapdragon 820 ║
╚══════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╝
* Dual-sim
```

---

If your device is in a state where you can't get as far as *Settings > About Device*, then you can resort instead to rebooting into *recovery mode* or into *ODIN mode*.

Recovery mode displays the model number `SM-G930F` like so:

```
Android Recovery
MMB29K.G930FXXU1BPHJ
samsung/heroltexx/herolte
6.0.1/MMB29K/G930FXXU1BPHJ
user/release-keys
```

And ODIN mode displays the model number `SM-G930F` like so:

```
ODIN MODE
Download speed: fast
Product name: SM-G930F
Current binary: Samsung official
System status: official
FRP lock: ON
Secure download: enabled
Warranty void: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:1 K:0 S:0
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Please install CPU-Z from Play Store. I had similar problem with my Samsung Galaxy NOTE4 N910C.
Link -> [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z)

Comment: Clearly fastest and safest answer. Thx